# How to indent a cone, like a rocket engine nozzle

Tags: modeling

I'd like to indent a cone on a RCS port I am making for Kerbal Space Program, I have the model mostly but do not have the RCS nozzles indented, they are just a cone. Here is a picture if that helps:

Reference:

[image]

Scene currently:
[image]

Comment: It helps to add more detail such as a reference image of what it is you are modeling so people that want to help can guide you the right direction.

Comment: Ok, I want it to look like this: http://www.space-propulsion.com/launcher-propulsion/rocket-engines/images/hm-7-nozzle.jpg

Comment: Try deleting the bottom face of the cone, if that's what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: hit the bottom face. press e to extrude s to reduce size then limit the axis, probably shift-z or z to scale only in 2 dimensions. type 0.9. this creates a ridge. press e to extrude again, g to manipulate position and shift the bottom of the cone upwards. (z direction) then scale down until it falls inside the outer cone.